# Is it safe to add Hyper-V role to a Windows Server 2008 R2 already running on production?

Tags: windows, hyper-v

Sorry for the newbie question, but I could not find an answer for it.

I have a Windows 2008 R2 Server in production running some applications, and I need to create a Virtual Machine to run a very light workload in that server to isolate another application, and keep running the actual applications on the "host".

I've read somewhere that when one adds the Hyper-V role on Windows 2008 R2 Server, the actual Windows installation becomes somewhat a "guest", running inside Hyper-V (because Hyper-V is a hypervisor).

It is safe to add the Hyper-V role in Windows already running on production? Should I expect breakages on the actual "host"?

Thanks!

Comment: You should always expect breakage and always assume that you'll need to rebuild from the ground up.

Comment: It should be safe, unless your applications are using the GPU or other hardware-specific resources.  But you still need to have a recovery plan.  (And you will of course need to reboot at least once.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have mission-critical applications running on a single server you already have a problem. If nothing else, I would plan for a reboot or two whenever you install anything system-level on Windows (though sometimes you'll be surprised by a major installation that doesn't require a reboot.)

Have backups and a recovery plan.